# How to Check Two Conditions in $Criteria->order() in Yii

Tags: yii

i have my criteria like the below:

```
   $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
   $Criteria->join='LEFT JOIN abc_tablename ON some_id=one_id';
   $Criteria->order = "created_date DESC,commented_date DESC";
```

the above code sorts only created_date but commented_date is not working... can any one help me in how to order with both the conditions working.

Comment: did you check by applying commented_date order criteria in next line as $Criteria->order = "commented_date DESC";

Comment: i tried but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I got the out put by using the following code.

```
    $Criteria->order = " CASE WHEN pc.commented_date IS NULL 
    THEN t.created_date WHEN pc.commented_date IS NOT NULL THEN 
    pc.commented_date ELSE 1 END  DESC";
```

Comment: pls try active record class than trying to execute sql query if u are trying to join two tables and sort them...